# Barracuda installation not possible on win10

Tags: windows, installation, vpn, windows-10

I am unable to install Barracuda Netwrok Access client on any win 10 PC.

Installation wizzard fails on the last screen few seconds after "Install" button was clicked on.

[image]

Installation wizzard was run as Administrator. I also tried to change the setup.exe compatibility properties with no effect.

In Windows Event Viewer I have found: "Installation was finished with success or error: 1603". Error 1603 means one of the following:

- Folder I want Barracuda install into is encryped (It is not)
- I want to install it onto a substitude drive (No)
- I do not have full controll permission on the installation folder (No. I also tried to change the folder location - with no effect)

My config:

- System: Win10 Pro
- Application: Barracuda 3.6

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. There must be MS Outlook turned off while trying to instal Barracuda. The problem was caused by MS Lync integration.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with version 5. In my case, there were a couple of services blocking the installation such as:

- MongoDB Server
- ESET Remote Administrator Agent

but the installer was only saying "**The wizard was interrupted...** "

To discover which services are blocking your specific situation, follow this procedure:

1. Run the installer (in my case *NetworkAccessClient_5.0.1-12_x64.exe*)
2. Open C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Temp and sort folders by creation date. The last one should be the one containing the BarracudaNAC.msi file. In my case was C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Local\Temp{1FD950A7-EDFE-40D2-8534-1C7960D8B012}
3. Copy the BarracudaNAC.msi file somewhere in your filesystem.(i.e. c:\Downloads)
4. Interrupt the installation you started at step 1
5. Run the installation again using the BarracudaNAC.msi instead of the original NetworkAccessClient executable.
6. One of the steps is the services check. Just terminate the services that are blocking your installation or select the "Do not close applications. (A reboot will be required)" option:
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltLAN.jpg)

Hope it helps.

Matteo

Comment: I had to run the BarracudaNAC.msi from task-manager (File->Run new task) after first killing Windows Explorer.  Then i had to close task-manager (the msi complained about it) and was able to get it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Three more apps that need to be closed: Google Chat (browser-based app), Windows Terminal Preview (NB! not cmd or ps), Slack. This list was displayed after "Validating install" message had been up for ~10 minutes. Then again 5 minutes "Validating install" and MS Teams Chat had to be closed (NB! also need to quit it from system tray). Alltogether about 40 min install...